# FreePBX configure wifi from command line WPA2

Tags: wifi, wlan, freepbx

I have computer that only have Wifi network. There is no RJ45 socket. I have to configure Wifi using command line.
My Wifi:

```
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
Connection mode        : Profile
Channel                : 1
```

On `FreePBX` I have file: `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
   ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
   ctrl_interface_group=wheel
   network={
      ssid="mynetworkname"
      psk="mypassword"
   }
```

When I type command:

```
   wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
```

and I get error:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Failed to open config file '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf', error: No such file or directory
Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface '/var/run/wpa_supplicant'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

Comment: Well, you've told it the wrong config file location, so how are you expecting it to work? Why don't you just pass it the absolute path?

Comment: make sure the file /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf exist!
if exist try with sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the full path to the configuration file `wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
killall wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```